# Is there a Eventrbrite Sql Script download available to create database locally

Tags: database, eventbrite

We would like to save Eventbrite events entered by our users onto a local databse and upload on a schedule to Eventbrite database.

I am in the process of creating a database with the base Eventbrite tables and wanted to find out if anyone can point me in the right direction? I am trying to locate the script that can help create the base tables for Eventbrite.

Please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: please ask a question where a specific answer can be given

Comment: Hi I am trying to find out if there is a location for this script? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd try constructing your SQL based on the schema outlined on Eventbrite's [Event object](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/) documentation page:
http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/

You can browse schema info for other object types by clicking on the object names in this list:
http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/#methods

Comment: Eventbrite changed their website.
[Event object](https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/api#/reference/event)
https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/api see "Reference" on left menu